# Save image on disk from byte array (using EF), A generic error occurred in GDI+

Tags: c#, image, winforms, arrays

I'm working on a winforms program that could get a byte array from a database, transform it as an image and save it on disk.

The picture is displayed well in the PictureBox element however when I try to save the file, code throw an error : "the generic error occurred in GDI+". The picture is generated in my folder, but is unreadable (weighs 0 octets).

```
var profilImage = (from user in _context.mytable
                            where user.Id == itemData.Id
                            select user.ProfilImage).FirstOrDefault();

Image DcImage = ByteArrayToImage(profilImage);
this.pictureBox1.Image = DcImage;

DcImage.Save(this.tb_choose_folder.Text + @"\test.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

method ByteArrayToImage()

```
// Convert a byte array to an image
    private Image ByteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArrayIn)
    {
        if(byteArrayIn == null)
        {
            throw new NullReferenceException("byteArrayIn");
        }

        using (MemoryStream mStream = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn))
        {
            return Image.FromStream(mStream);
        }
    }
```

And here is how I tranform my image to an byte array :

```
System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(@"myFolder\test_1.jpg");
        System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
        image.Save(ms,System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);

        var imageByteArray = ms.ToArray();
```

imageByteArray is put in a sql server Image type field

Thanks for your advices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do any of that.  Your bytes are already a JPEG file; you can read and write them from disk using `File.ReadAllBytes()` and `File.WriteAllBytes()`.